# How to Allow New User to Add Products in opencart or nopcommerce

Tags: php, .net, wordpress, opencart, nopcommerce

I am going to build my own Ecommerce site . But the thing i want is any user that come to my site can add products like what happens in olx . It means i want any user that came to my site if want to add or sell his/her own products or thing can upload that product

I have three options for This site

```
Nopcommerce
opencart
woocommerce
```

Comment: can you tell in more detail

Comment: When a user registers they are given the Subscriber role, which by default don't have permission to add new products.

Comment: can we edit that roles

Comment: Sorry I miss read the question. 2 minutes

Comment: Changing the users role to "Shop Manager" should work.

Comment: When you edit a users profile, about 1/3rd of the way down the page

Comment: i am using 1.5.5.1 version of opencart but i am unable to find this where is this open .

Comment: I was referring to WooCommerce. I'm not sure how to do it fro the others.

Comment: OpenCart does not have such feature by default but there is/are some paid module/s for this.

Answer (score 1):

nopCommerce has multi-vendor support. This way registered vendors can manage its own catalog and sell products. But please note that vendors are registered by a store owner out of the box. If you want to allow customers to be registered as vendors manually (not by a store owner), then it'll require some minor customization. But other 99% of your requirements are already implemented

Comment: can you tell some more about how to do that customization

Answer (score -1):

[Opencart MultiVendors Module](http://multimerch.com/) tried it, works good, price is not that big of a deal in case of modding existing nopCommerce in ASP.NET, server cost will be lower.